# how to disable softkeyboard in an activity?

Tags: android, keyboard

I want to disable keyboard pop up in my activity. There will not be any keboard in the actvity. but hardware keyboard must work.how to do this? hardware buttons must work

Comment: could you explain more clearly what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Just try below code.

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editView.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this in your manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".SampleActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Managing soft keyboard in android is not that easy, although you can hide keyboard programatically.

```
private void hideKeyboard() {   
    //This will get any view in focus.
    View view = this.getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) this.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    }
}
```

note that Hardware Keyboard will work.